# Push Notification of posts on Android app from blog

Tags: android

I am making a small app for my website with just WebView. Now What i want is to When User doesn't even use the app.. the app should check for new posts from the website and push a notification to device that new post is available.

Comment: u need to write a service which check the available posts

Comment: Service name or any sample syntax would b of great help..  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use google cloud messaging service (GCM). Using this service, you can notify the changes on your blog to google server, which in turn send push notifications to registered mobile devices.

If you are using Wordpress platform then there is a plugin WP-GCM for this purpose.

Comment: First of all i would like to thank u.. this was my first question on this site and u answerd it so quick.    I am using blogger and trying to make a android app out of it with just a simple webview. i am new to android i made the app but i want it to push notification to app whenever i post new post.  Please Any syntax or sample format to use GCM would be of great help And Thank u for the help :)